# Recharts is not workingReact with typescript with yarn

Tags: reactjs, react-typescript, recharts

I have installed recharts by using,
yarn add recharts
yarn add @types/recharts

my Chart.tsx file is:

```
import "./chart.scss";
import {
  AreaChart,
  Area,
  XAxis,
  CartesianGrid,
  Tooltip,
  ResponsiveContainer,
} from "recharts";

const data = [
  { name: "January", Total: 1200 },
  { name: "February", Total: 2100 },
  { name: "March", Total: 800 },
  { name: "April", Total: 1600 },
  { name: "May", Total: 900 },
  { name: "June", Total: 1700 },
];

const Chart = ({ aspect, title }:any) => {
  return (
    <div className="chart">
      <div className="title">{title}</div>
      <ResponsiveContainer width="100%" aspect={aspect}>
        <AreaChart
          width={730}
          height={250}
          data={data}
          margin={{ top: 10, right: 30, left: 0, bottom: 0 }}
        >
          <defs>
            <linearGradient id="total" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="1">
              <stop offset="5%" stopColor="#8884d8" stopOpacity={0.8} />
              <stop offset="95%" stopColor="#8884d8" stopOpacity={0} />
            </linearGradient>
          </defs>
          <XAxis dataKey="name" stroke="gray" />
          {/* <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" className="chartGrid" /> */}
          <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" />
          <Tooltip />
          <Area
            type="monotone"
            dataKey="Total"
            stroke="#8884d8"
            fillOpacity={1}
            fill="url(#total)"
          />
        </AreaChart>
      </ResponsiveContainer>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Chart;
```

But don't know why its giving below error,

```
webpack compiled successfully
ERROR in src/views/Dashboard/Chart.tsx:9:8
TS2307: Cannot find module 'recharts' or its corresponding type declarations.
     7 |   Tooltip,
     8 |   ResponsiveContainer,
  >  9 | } from "recharts";
       |        ^^^^^^^^^^
    10 |
    11 | const data = [
    12 |   { name: "January", Total: 1200 },
```

Thanks in advance....

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum pariatur cumque odit quaerat saepe ratione dolorum excepturi eveniet doloremque quis expedita quasi vero, dignissimos ipsum totam possimus maiores quia debitis illo consectetur soluta in qui? Iure eum beatae ipsam?